# MySql data reader does not retrieve the row

Tags: c#, mysql

I am making an Xamarin application with MySQL database. I want to get the values `leerlinggebruikersnaam` and `leerlingwachtwoord` from my table `leerlinglogin` but when i fill in the correct `username` and `password` it still goes to the else statement with `inlog invalid` here is the code I am using in my Visual Studio:

```
void LoginKlik(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Server=arabig.nl;Port=3306;database=arabignl_project;User Id=arabignl_project;Password=**password**;charset=utf8");
            try
            {
                con.Open();

                MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand("SELECT leerlinggebruikersnaam, leerlingwachtwoord FROM arabignl_project.myfirstmodule$leerlinglogin WHERE(leerlinggebruikersnaam  = @gebruiker AND leerlingwachtwoord = @wachtwoord)", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gebruiker", LeerlingGebruikersnaam);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@wachtwoord", LeerlingWachtwoord);

                MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        LoginLog.Text = "Inloggen gelukt";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    LoginLog.Text = "Inloggen mislukt";
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                LoginLog.Text = ex.ToString();
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

And here is the Database line:

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7paA.png)

Comment: You mean it doesn't come inside if (reader.HasRows) statement or while loop is not reached, or you mean that you can't get data?

Comment: The row is not coming into the datareader

Comment: In your data, LeerlingGebruikersnaam i set to 313816. It looks like the username is actually leerlingachternaam. To me, 'Renoaline' looks more like a username than 313816.

Comment: With `LeerlingGebruikersnaam = "313816"` and `LeerlingWachtwoord = "Jari"` I am able to "log in" with this code just fine. As @simonatrcl said, check that you're using the right column names.